# Communicating between ViewModels with Events

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to communicate events from my child ViewModel back to the parent.  The child viewmodel's view is a separate window that I believe I cannot pass constructor arguments to.  A button on this view needs to trigger a method on the parent ViewModel.

Child ViewModel:

```
public ConnectViewModel(ConnectEvents connectEvents)
{
    ConnectEvents = connectEvents;
}
```

Parent ViewModel

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    ConnectEvents connectEvents = new ConnectEvents();
    ConnectViewModel = new ConnectViewModel(connectEvents);
    connectEvents.ThrowEvent += ConnectToServer;
}
```

How can I communicate between these two?  Is there a better system, or how can I allow the parents to subscribe to the child?

Comment: If you're really want to implement MVVM, you should take a look a the Command Pattern.

Comment: Is it possible to pass commands to another viewmodel?  They have different dataContexts.

Comment: This is what it does, look at the definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a lot of choices. You can use [custom event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx), you can use [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) directly, you can subscribe in your parent ViewModel to the [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) or [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) event, using either ordinary subscription, or [Weak Event Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx).

I prefer the last one because there is no need to unsubscribe from.

Answer (score 7):

You can make your own EventAggregator

```
public static class DumbAggregator
{
  public static void BroadCast(string message)
  {
   if (OnMessageTransmitted != null)
       OnMessageTransmitted(message);
  }

 public static Action<string> OnMessageTransmitted;
}
```

Usage:

```
  public class MySender
  {
    public void SendMessage()
    {
      DumbAggregator.BroadCast("Hello There!");
    }
  }

public class MySubscriber
{
  public MySubscriber()
  {
   DumbAggregator.OnMessageTransmitted += OnMessageReceived;
  }

 private void OnMessageReceived(string message)
 {
  MessageBox.Show("I Received a Message! - " + message);
 }
}
```

and with the help of this you can communicate with your view models

Comment: just for other people who are using this as well for each subscriber you might want them all to do different things.  So instead of creating a class you can just DumbAggregator.OnMessageTransmitted += OnMessageReceived;
 in each classes constructor and then create specific if cases on message receive depending on the message coming through.  This gives a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

Communicate 'events' by using events

In your ConnectViewModel...

```
public ConnectViewModel(ConnectEvents connectEvents)
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> SomethingHappenedEvent;

     ...

     private void DoSomething()
     {
          if (SomethingHappenedEvent != null)
          {
              SomethingHappenedEvent(this, newEventArgs());
          }
     }

     RelayComand _somethingCommand;
     public ICommand SomethingHappenedCommand
     {   
          get
          {
              if (_someethingCommand == null)
                   _somethingCommand = new RelayCommand(DoSomething)
           }
     }
}
```

and in your MainWindowViewModel

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    ConnectEvents connectEvents = new ConnectEvents();
    ConnectViewModel = new ConnectViewModel(connectEvents);
    ConnectViewModel.SomethingHappenedEvent += HandleSomethingHappened;
    connectEvents.ThrowEvent += ConnectToServer;
}
private void HandleSomethingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Now your mainviewmodel knows that something happened
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example the utilizes the [WeakEventManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.weakeventmanager-2?view=net-5.0) mentioned in the accepted answer.

```cs
namespace Stuff {
    using System;
    using System.Windows;

    // An "event bus" public to all view models.
    public sealed class Events {
        public static Events Instance { get; } = new Events();

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs>? SomethingHappend;

        private Events() { }

        public static void RaiseSomethingHappend(object? sender = null)
            => Instance.SomethingHappend?.Invoke(sender ?? Instance, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    // A view model that wants to listen to one or more events.
    public class Listener {
        public Listener() {
            WeakEventManager<Events, EventArgs>.AddHandler(
                source: Events.Instance,
                eventName: nameof(Events.SomethingHappend),
                Handle);
        }

        private void Handle(object? sender, EventArgs args) { }
    }

    // A view model that raises events.
    public class Source {
        public void Foo() {
            Events.RaiseSomethingHappend();
        }
    }
}
```